# How to display full URL in php without js

Tags: string, url, hyperlink, header

How to display full URL  which are comeing in url 
MY url is ('http://localhost/test/callback.php#access_token=sdfg46f5g45f4d65fg4d6sdgsd4df65d4g5d465dsf4g')

Here to find access_token

**Don't use javascript,jquery**

Answer (score 0):

What is after the hashbang doesn't get sent to the server.

However, in the client, you can see it with:

```
> window.location.hash
>> #access_token=sdfg46f5g45f4d65fg4d6sdgsd4df65d4g5d465dsf4g
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything after a `#` in a URL is an anchor tag. Browsers don't send this to the server, so there isn't any way to access it in PHP.

You should be using GET or POST parameters. For GET parameters, just change the `#` to a `?`

So the url will look like this

```
http://localhost/test/callback.php?access_token=sdfg46f5g45f4d65fg4d6sdgsd4df65d4g5d465dsf4g
```

And then in PHP you can access `access_token` using `$_GET["access_token"]`